# Error during mpich configuration. How do I unset/set environmental variables?

Tags: mpich

I have a new linux system I am setting up and I am trying to install MPICH. I downloaded the source code from `http://www.mpich.org/` and have extracted the .tar.gz file. The next step I understand is to configure with `./configure` however I get an error message at the end of the configuration.

```
"configure: error: F90 and F90FLAGS are replaced by FC and FCFLAGS respectively in this configure, please unset F90/F90FLAGS and set FC/FCFLAGS instead and rerun configure again."
```

How do I unset `F90/F90FLAGS` and set the `FC/FCFLAGS`?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your shell environment. For example, to unset environment variables in bash, you would run `unset F90`.

Another question is do you really need to build the fortran bindings for mpich? If not, you can add the flags `--disable-f77 --disable-fc` to your configure.

Comment: It seems like you might be using redhat.  Unless you need the latest version, you can try (as root) `yum install mpich2 mpich2-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Unset them before configure:

```
unset F90
unset F90FLAGS
./configure
```